# Karma Configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner

When I right-click in IntelliJ to run a Jasmine test in Karma this conf file is passed to Karma:

C:\Users\jpatterson.IntellJIdea2018\config\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellij.conf.js

How can I get Karma to use the karma.conf.js file associated with my project?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your Karma run/debug configuration.

Answer (score 2):

`intellij.conf.js` is a helper that actually loads your karma configuration file, parses it and does some preprocessing (coverage configuring, sourcemaps, etc). There is no way to avoid using this config when running Karma from IDEA. But you shouldn't normally care about this, as your `karma.conf.js` is still used

Comment: There is no prolem if I run a Configuration, but if I right-click on the source file and run a single test I get "ERROR [preprocess]: Can not load "typescript", it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?"

Comment: strange... please check the configuration that is created when you right-click a file (it should be available in Run | Edit configurations) - what does it look like? sample project that shows up the issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have to update your default Karma run configuration.

Go to:

Run > Edit Configurations... > Defaults > Karma and set the needed paths there.